# onErrorResume() won't get called

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm newbie to spring webflux and reactor I want to have a fallback mechanism when some specific exception occurs and based on my research onErrorResume method does that but it won't get called and I get 500 internal server error instead of my fallback triggered and preventing this error.

Note: I use spring webflux which means it made some changes in the normal behavior of the reactor project

```
public Mono<Date> getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
    return getAllClaimsFromToken(token)
            .onErrorResume(ExpiredJwtException.class, e -> Mono.just(e.getClaims()))
            .map(Claims::getExpiration);
}

public Mono<Claims> getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Mono.just(Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes()))
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody());
}
```

and this is the stack trace

```
    io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2020-03-22T08:17:15Z. Current time: 2020-03-22T08:50:56Z, a difference of 2021835 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:439) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler ir.siavash.customerservice.security.controller.AuthController#refreshToken(Mono) [DispatcherHandler]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/auth/refreshToken" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:439) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:601) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at ir.siavash.customerservice.security.JWTUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(JWTUtil.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Can you provide more onformation about your error please ? A stack-trace would help. In your example, only ExpiredJwtException would trigger fallback. Any other error would propagate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, On second look, it's clear. That's a common mistake. Reactive components could be difficult to learn, but  you're not very far from the solution.

Mono.just takes a *pre-computed* value as parameter. Therefore, your *getAllClaimsFromToken* will create a Mono only after all code given to *just* is executed. That means that your error happens before any reactive component is available for error management (assembly time).

What you could do instead is using [Mono#fromCallable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) to ask Reactor to compute Jwt token on demand, or creating Mono with just initial string, then mapping using your function.

Let's see second solution:

```java
public Mono<Date> getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
    return Mono.just(token)
            .map(this::getAllClaimsFromToken)
            .onErrorResume(ExpiredJwtException.class, e -> Mono.just(e.getClaims()))
            .map(Claims::getExpiration);
}

public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes()))
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging remarks and your nice explanation about what is going on behind the scenes I completely understand, and it works properly now